# How do I go about creating a dynamic grid QScrollarea in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qscrollarea, qgridlayout

I'm developing some custom software that involves creating a workspace and working in it. I want to display all the existing workSpace directories in a dynamic scrollarea grid comprised of buttons that changes the positions of the buttons depending on the amount of screen real estate the scrollarea is taking up so that as many buttons as possible are inserted in the highest possible row.( So basically like the file explorer changes the layout of the folders and files to fit the screen in a grid depending on how you resize the window) I tried doing this using a gridlayout inside the scrollarea. I also tried to add qhboxlayouts in a qvboxlayout to no avail since I had no idea how to check whether there is space for another button to remove one from a lower qhboxlayout and append to a higher one.

This is my current code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog

class Ui_AutoCal(object):
    def setupUi(self, AutoCal):
        AutoCal.setObjectName("AutoCal")
        AutoCal.resize(513, 551)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(AutoCal.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        AutoCal.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        AutoCal.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor))
        AutoCal.setStyleSheet("*{\n"
"background-color: rgb(54, 54, 54);\n"
"color:rgb(255,255,255)\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton\n"
"{\n"
"border-radius: 25px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QLineEdit\n"
"{\n"
"color:rgb(0,0,0)\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(AutoCal)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.groupBox.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.groupBox.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.groupBox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lineEdit.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lineEdit.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        # self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openFileNameDialog )

        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout_6.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.verticalLayout_6.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox_2.setEnabled(True)
        self.groupBox_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.groupBox_2)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.groupBox_2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollArea.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollArea.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        # self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 467, 331))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.fillScrollArea()

        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.groupBox_2)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3)
        AutoCal.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(AutoCal)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 513, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuWorkSpace = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuWorkSpace.setObjectName("menuWorkSpace")
        self.menuRecipients = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuRecipients.setObjectName("menuRecipients")
        AutoCal.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(AutoCal)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        AutoCal.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuWorkSpace.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuRecipients.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(AutoCal)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(AutoCal)

    def retranslateUi(self, AutoCal):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        AutoCal.setWindowTitle(_translate("AutoCal", "AutoCal"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("AutoCal", "Create New WorkSpace"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("AutoCal", "Choose WorkSpace Directory"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("AutoCal", "Browse"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("AutoCal", "WorkSpace Name"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("AutoCal", "Create"))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("AutoCal", "Choose Existing WorkSpace"))
        self.menuWorkSpace.setTitle(_translate("AutoCal", "WorkSpace"))
        self.menuRecipients.setTitle(_translate("AutoCal", "Recipients"))

    def fillScrollArea(self):

        for i in range(50):
            for j in range(50):
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton("Test"), i, j)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    AutoCal = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_AutoCal()
    ui.setupUi(AutoCal)
    AutoCal.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This produces the following scrollArea (ignore the forms):

Current Scroll Area

[image]

The main problem is that i need the buttons to always be in the visible section of the scrollArea, whereas as you can see many of them are hidden behind the scrollarea and their text is cut off. I know this is because of the positioning that my function applies to the grid layout but I'm not aware of any other way to position them. I also need the buttons to be dynamic in the sense that if horizontal space becomes greater in a higher row, the ones in the lower row will take up that space. Because of this I dont need horizontal scrolling either, which is why it's disabled.

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: @eyllanesc Which part do you find unclear?

Comment: What is your problem? You just set your objective, launch an incomplete code, and nothing else. So if you want help point out the error or unexpected behavior that you have now in addition to providing a [mre]

Comment: Also read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: 1. You still don't provide the MRE, 2. Is the width of the window fixed or changing? I ask because it is clear that the number of horizontal widgets depends on the width. For example, let's say that for a width of 200 there are 5 items and in total there are 20 items, so there are 4 rows, then what should happen if the width increases to 400? Does the number of items have to be increased horizontally so should the number of rows decrease?

Comment: I added an image showing the result and explained a bit further what I'm having trouble with. I'm not sure what more i could include as a minimal reproducible example, the only part that i have a problem with is the scrollarea, so i included only that. The only other thing i could have included is the class and init function which i found redundant to include, but I could include it if that's necessary. Please let me know if there's anything else that's unclear.

Comment: 1) An MRE helps us, you must pay attention to the reproducibility capacity: We should do a copy-paste to be able to execute the code and then reproduce the problem, but with that piece of code it is not possible. 2) Answer the question from my previous comment.

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes the user should be able to change the size to see more and the number of items in a higher row should increase if the horizontal space is greater and thus the number of items in a lower row should decrease.

Comment: hmm okay i will prepare a sample class for you then

Comment: Use flowlayout, see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyqt%5D+flowlayout

Comment: Note that if you need to add "widgets" that are all almost identical in concept, you could consider using a QListView or QListWidget with the icon mode (instead of the standard list mode) and a custom item delegate to display them. That's how Qt shows the contents of a directory in a tree view or a non native file dialog.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is now resolved. While flow layout was useful, it was much more intuitive to simply use QListWidget. Many thanks to both eyllanesc and musicamante for their help.

For anyone who has the same issue, the desired result can be achieved by simply creating a QlistWidget and adding items to it:

```
size = QSize(100,100)
self.listWidget = QListWidget()
size = QtCore.QSize(80,80)
self.listWidget.setResizeMode(QListView.Adjust)
self.listWidget.setIconSize(size)
self.listWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.itemClicked)
self.listWidget.setViewMode(QListView.IconMode)
```